# Decimal separator while importing a flat file in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have an issue while importing a flat file into SSMS. As I download a CSV file from a specific system, the decimal separator is always ".". I have a regional setting of comma and I use commas all the time. But when importing these CSV files into SSMS, I get an error of type mismatch, due to the fact that SSMS cannot recognize the values as numbers (float, decimal, etc.)

I have tried to switch the regional Windows settings and replaced dot with a comma, which solved the issue and imported the file, but the question is, am I able to change settings in SSMS somehow so I am able to keep comma as default but import CSV files with decimal point separator?

I need to work only with SSMS, I am unable to install SSIS packages.

Thank you very much for any feedback.

Comment: Side-note, you don't import *into SSMS*, you import *into* SQL Server.

Comment: Import *how*? SSMS has at least two ways to do this and both can handle regional settings and different separators. The `Import Data` task for example creates an SSIS package that can be modified.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you very much for your feedback. I am a beginner to this field so please apologize my terminology. 

I am using the Import flat file task in SSMS. I am used to Excel for all data analyses and when importing csv into Excel there is a option of selecting decimal separator at the end of the import so all the points change to commas in the result and thus the type is recognized as number, I was wondering if there is anything similar possible in the case of SSMS. Could I find this in the Import Data option?

Comment: @Stu thank you very much for the feedback, as mentioned I am a beginner to this filed and I need to work on my terminology

Comment: Try this: In SSMS select "Import Data" option then in "Data Source" select "Flat File Source". Select file to load and then change "Locale" option (located just below file name).

Comment: @Alex Thank you very much Alex, this worked and I successfully imported the file with commas instead of decimal points. It really helped, thank you so much!

Comment: Posting this as answer in case someone else may need it. I was not sure originally if it would work, and no way to test quickly as I do not have other locales installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS select "Import Data" option then in "Data Source" select "Flat File Source". Select file to load and then change "Locale" option (located just below file name).

Locales control how data formats are displayed and interpreted such as currency symbols and radix (decimal separator) character.

[image]